# Dynamodb sorting and filtering by multiple keys

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to store three main columns to save the score for a user against a time

```
User        DateTime                     Score
1           2018-01-01-09-00             5
1           2015-11-24-11-32             2
2           2014-11-24-11-32             1
3           2016-11-24-11-32             3
```

Functionality I require/is easier:

- User/datetime needs to be unique - (so was going to use it as a partition/range key)
- Score needs to be incremented atomically using `UpdateExpression: "ADD #C :num"`  ( they can score 5 times within a minute, rather than getting a score of 5)
- Need to retrieve a specific user/time score entry

The complex bit gets when I need to:

- Need to retrieve all the entries where datetime contains a certain part (e.g. could be 2018, could be 2018-01) - within a 'query' so is efficient retrieval, but sorted by Score. This lets me find out the highest score for a user by day, month, year, hour etc.

This leaves complications due to:

1. 'Score' can't be used as part of a compound key, as it is atomically increased.
2. DateTime has to be in range key due to requiring to use 'BeginsWith'

The only way I can see doing this is by having two tables:

```
User        DateTime            compound    
(partition) (range key)               
1           2018-01-01-09-00    1#2018-01-01-09-00          
1           2015-11-24-11-32    1#2015-11-24-11-32               
2           2018-01-01-09-00    2#2018-01-01-09-00    
3           2016-11-24-11-32    3#2018-01-01-09-00
```

Table 2:

```
user#DateTime                     Score
(partition key)                   (range key)
1#2018-01-01-09-00                5
1#2015-11-24-11-32                2
2#2014-11-24-11-32                1
3#2016-11-24-11-32                3
```

Doing two queries where 
 1. get the list of DateTimes that begin with (2018-01*)
 2. get the Score for all the datetimes returned.

However this seems excessive as has multiple queries.

Is there something obvious being missed, as it seems a prime candidate for dynamodb as simple lookup.

I don't want to save every stage of the date seperately e.g. 2018, 2018-01, 2018-01-01, 2018-01-09 as this seems very excessively duplication and requires may writes to update.

Ideally i would have a compound range key of 
score#dateTime, but I cannot do this due to score having to be updated atomically.